# Phoenix/ Elixir Genserver won't start automatically. Error: shutdown: failed to start child

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a `GenServer` in a module called `CameraServer` that fetches images which are then used by certain endpoints in the Phoenix Application.

```
defmodule MyApp.CameraServer do
  @name :image_server
  use GenServer

  def start_link(_opts) do
    IO.puts("Starting image server")
    GenServer.start(__MODULE__, [], name: @name)
    IO.puts("Image server started")
  end

  def get_images(_pid) do
    GenServer.call(@name, :clear)
  end

  def get_images(_pid, mac_address) do
    GenServer.call(@name, {:view, mac_address})
  end

  ## Genserver Server Code
  def init([]) do
    images = ["image_0", ...] 
    {:ok, images}
  end

  def handle_call(:clear, _sender, state) do
    {:reply, state, state}
  end

  def handle_call({:view, mac_address}, _sender, state) do
    results = Enum.filter(state, &String.contains?(&1, mac_address))
    {:reply, results, state}
  end
end
```

And my `application.ex` file is as follows.

```
defmodule MyApp.Application do
  # See https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html
  # for more information on OTP Applications
  @moduledoc false

  use Application

  @impl true
  def start(_type, _args) do
    children = [
      MyApp.CameraServer,
      # Start the Ecto repository
      MyApp.Repo,
      # Start the Telemetry supervisor
      MyApp.Telemetry,
      # Start the PubSub system
      {Phoenix.PubSub, name: MyApp.PubSub},
      # Start the Endpoint (http/https)
      MyApp.Endpoint
    ]

    # See https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html
    # for other strategies and supported options
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: MyApp.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
  ...
end
```

Now, when I run `mix phx.server`, I will get the error

> ** (Mix) Could not start application myapp: MyApp.Application.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: MyApp.CameraServer
> ** (EXIT) :ok

Strange thing is that I am able to see in the logs the outputs:

> Starting image server

> Image server started

Additionally, I can also run `iex -S mix phx.server` and then manually run `MyApp.CameraServer.start_link([])` and then it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem in the `MyApp.CameraServer.start_link/1`. You put `IO.puts("Image server started")` as the last statement, and it returns `:ok`, which is not a valid return value [`start_link/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#start_link/3) should return. It’s not a callback, hence it lacks an explicit contract, but implicitly it’d be added to the application supervision tree, which requires a proper return value to succeed.

You can change it to

```
  def start_link(_opts) do
    IO.puts("Starting image server")
    
    case GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: @name) do
      {:ok, server} ->
        IO.puts("Image server started")
        {:ok, server}

      error ->
        IO.puts("Image server failed to start: #{inspect error}")
        error
    end
  end
```

By the way, I changed `GenServer.start` to `GenServer.start_link`, because you want your `CameraServer` process to link to its supervisor.